# SQl Trim problem

Tags: sql, oracle, trim

I am trying to pull data from table using this select statement..

```
SELECT ID_NO
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE trim(SYN_NO) ='21IT';
```

SYN_NO column hold data in this format

```
21IT / 00065421
```

I want to get just first four characters and drop rest of it.. i tried trim, rtrim but it didnt work. Is there a way to do this.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly for those of us coming from SQL Server, there is no `LEFT` in oracle. The article I linked below talks about one person's encounter with this problem, and recommends using

```
SUBSTR(SYN_NO,1,4)
```

([see article](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/using-left-and-charindex-in-oracle/))

[Oracle SUBSTR specification](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm)

Comment: @Justin thanks, noticed that and fixed it before your comment came through, hah.

Comment: or WHERE SYN_NO LIKE '21IT'||'%';

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just realized this is Oracle. You need to use `SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT ID_NO
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE SUBSTR(SYN_NO, 1, 4) ='21IT';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you'd use the `SUBSTR` function

```
SELECT id_no
  FROM employee
 WHERE substr(syn_no,1,4) = '21IT'
```